# Rest 'guidelines' make the API design difficult

Tags: rest, restful-url, restful-architecture

I am trying to create an API for my Rest services and i am struggling with the design rules that i try to follow. In generally i am trying to follow (among others) these guidelines:

1. Don't use verbs in the URIs
2. Don't use query parameters when altering states
3. Use plural
4. Don't use camel case

Now, i have to model something like the following:

- Get all departments of a company
- Get a department of a company
- Delete all deprtaments of a company
- Delete a department of a company

I am trying something like this:

```
GET company/departments
GET company/departments/<depName>
DELETE company/departments
DELETE company/departments  {body: department name}
```

The above, follows the guidelines that i have mentioned, but i really don't think that the resulted URIs are good. Especially the fourth, does a different job and has the same URI as the third.

This is a common problem for me, and i encounter it many times when i am designing REST services. The result is that i always break some designing principles to achieve what i want or make uglier URIs (for example: DELETE company/departments/department).

---

So the actual question is:

In my design, how can i delete a single department with a Restfull-like URI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A URL consists of several parts:

```
http://example.com/company/departments/12345?arg1=this&arg2=that
```

`http:` is the scheme. `//example.com` is the host. `/company/departments/12345` is the path, `?arg1=this&arg2=that` is the query string, consisting of two parameters: arg1 and arg2. There's another aspect, called matrix arguments, which won't be discussed here.

When REST talks about URLs, it refers to the entire thing. Not parts of it. To REST the entire URL is treated as an opaque blob.

That means REST doesn't care about any particular part: the scheme, the host, the path, or the arguments.

`ftp://127.0.0.1/E280F814-1524-41D5-8735-43D8414AE242` is a perfectly fine URL as far as REST is concerned.

So as far as REST is concerned, it doesn't give a rip what path you use in your URL or whether you use parameters or not.

That said, the recommendations against parameters in a URL is because sometimes, caches don't cache paramaterized URLs properly. Thus the preference for `/company/department/12345` over `/company/department?id=12345`.

The `12345` in the path is not a parameter. Its the name of the resource. Just like `starwars.mp4` above is not a parameter, nor is `E280F814-1524-41D5-8735-43D8414AE242`. They're just names. The only folks that actually care are people. The computer doesn't care, the internet doesn't care, REST doesn't care. To them, it's just all bits.

So it sounds like a simple miscommunication that you're fighting. Try not to stress over it too much. Too much weight is pressed on URL naming anyway, when it's the resources and their representations that actually matter.

Answer (score 4):

A better design for RESTful URIs is to use an identifier for the resource.  In this case the resource is the department.

So your URIs could be like the following:

```
GET company/departments  
GET company/departments/<department-id>  
DELETE company/departments  
DELETE company/departments/<department-id>
```

For example...

```
DELETE company/departments/58491
```

By using an identifier, rather than the department name, this avoids spaces in your URIs, which is undesirable.  By department name, i assume you meant the user friendly display name, such as "Human Capital Management."

Comment: This is what i want to do, but by doing this i violate a pretty important rule: '2.Don't use query parameters when altering states'. Am i wrong?

Comment: The '/58491' is not a query parameter. DELETE company/departments?id=58491 -- that's a query parameter.

Comment: but this is still a parameter in the url (maybe i shouldn't use the term 'query parameter'). In general, i try to follow the rules i gathered, but there are too restrictive. Do you think i shouldn't take them too serius?

Answer (score 0):

I agree. You should use URL like below to delete a department. Such URL identify a department and can be used to execute HTTP operations on it. Don't provide the department id or name within the payload of the request.

```
DELETE company/departments/58491
```

The following link could give you some more details about designing a RESTful service: https://templth.wordpress.com/2014/12/15/designing-a-web-api/.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry